# CSS- make image fill NOT STRETCH circular div?

Tags: html, css

I know there are many many questions n this but even after looking at several I am having a hard time. I need to make an image scale up to fill BUT NOT STRETCH (keep spect ratio) in a div.

Here is the html:

```
<div class = "profileimage"><img src = "image.jpeg"/> </div>
```

Then in css I set the image width to 100% and size the div correctly but still not getting the right result -

[image]

This is what Im getting (just image full width):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgetting `overflow`

```
  overflow:hidden;
```

```css
.profileimage{
position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}
.profileimage img{max-width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class = "profileimage"><img src = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/professions/512/user_boy_avatar-512.png"/> </div>
```

Comment: kudos! best answer